# Django cooking recipes site model structure

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, model

I'm working on Django website that should give a possibility to select cooking recipes containing the ingredients provided by user. So in brief, the idea of the site is "things you could make from the food in your refrigerator".

So I made 2 models

```
class Recipe (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)

class Ingredient (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Let's imagine, that I have as list `['egg','bread','meat','onion']`.

Now I need select all Recipes that could be made from that list on ingredients. 
The problem is, that some recipes may have only some of ingredients from the list.
For example:

- Egg Toast = egg + bread
- Meat Egg Toast = meat + egg + bread
- Meat with Onion = meat + onion
- and etc...

So my question is: could it be possible to select all recipes that could be made from the list of the ingredients AND select the closest recipes that could be made from the list of ingredients + some ingredients from the shop?

For example: recipes has 3 elements from 4, so we add it to the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found one solution. Using the code

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
def all_subsets(ss):
    return chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(ss, x), range(0, len(ss)+1)))
```

I'm able to select all possible combinations of ingredients from the lists.

```
for s in all_subsets(['egg','bread','meat','onion']):
    if len(s)>2:
        print s
```

Gives me result

> ('egg', 'bread', 'meat')
>   ('egg', 'bread', 'onion')
>   ('egg', 'meat', 'onion')
>   ('bread', 'meat', 'onion')
>   ('egg', 'bread', 'meat', 'onion')

Now the problem is how to optimize the query so I can select all recipes containing the list of this ingredient. In MongoDB I was using

```
receipts.find({'ingredients.name':{'$all':ingredients_list}})
```

Is there any alternative solution for MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
Receipt.objects.filter(ingredients__name__in=['egg','bread','meat','onion'])
```

Comment: Should that be `ingredients__name__in=['egg', 'bread', 'meat', 'onion']`?

Comment: Good catch! Just fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: yes, I tried that from the start, but the problem is that it gives me very large list without any ordering and sorting. There are a lots of recipes made from eggs and none made from egg + bread.

Comment: Ah, so in other words it gives you recipes with at least one of the ingredients, not all (or all less one, etc.)?

Comment: You could chain filters and use individual elements for e.g.: Receipt.objects.filter(ingredients__name='egg').filter(ingredients__name='bread')....
Obviously a messy solution but can't think of any other. What DB are you using? Can you resort to raw sql?

Comment: Yes, you are right. In my view, there should be some kind of rating or something like that, dunno how to make it. The recipe, which contains the largest number of ingredients gets the first place and then in descending order.

Comment: @Sid I use MySQL (MyISAM table) and I can use raw sql queries without any problems. Chaining ingredients will not have any result, because from 4 components you can make 2 different receipes containing completely different ingredients.

Comment: @Sid: If multiple `.filter` operations would actually work, the OP could use `reduce` to make it happen over the whole list: `qs = reduce(lambda qs, ingredient: qs.filter(ingredients__name=ingredient), ['egg', 'bread', 'meat', 'onion'], Recipe.objects)`

Comment: @PlatinumAzure thanks for your answer, but that does not work because user may enter ['egg', 'bread', 'meat', 'onion'] and receipe containing only egg, bread and opinion will not be selected because it does not contain meat.

Comment: I think this scenario is complex enough to warrant raw sql. Just go with that. Your query may become more complex in the future.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure neat solution with reduce!